# Reading lines from file with while(getline()) not working

Tags: c++

```
ifstream out("output.txt");
string search = "input1";
int count = 0;

while (getline(out, temp));
{
    if (temp.find(search))
    {
        count++;
    }
}

cout << "Total times input1 is present in output.txt: " << count << endl;
```

I am trying to count the number of times "input1" shows up in my output file. `cout` shows 1, when it should show 4. Putting a `cout` between the `while` and `if` statements shows that my `getline()` is not reading a line.

While testing, I used `getline()` before this `while` loop, and it picked everything up just fine.

Output.txt:

> This is the first line in input1.txt. 
>   This is the first line in input2.txt. 
>   This is the second line in input1.txt. 
>   This is the second line in input2.txt. 
>   This is the third line in input1.txt. 
>   This is the third line in input2.txt. 
>   This is the fourth line in input1.txt. 
>   This is the fourth line in input2.txt.

After a while of testing and searching the internet I still have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: One possible reason is that [using namespace std is bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice). Who knows which getline() you're really calling...

Comment: This code doesn't count the number of lines in which `"input1"` appears. It counts the number of lines which do not start with `"input1"`.

Comment: Why the semicolon after `while (getline(out, temp))` exists?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but it's odd to have an input file named `out`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolon after `while (getline(out, temp))` is getting the block containing the `if` statement out of the loop and having the `find` function see only the last line in the file. Try removing it.

Comment: Wow I am dumb. Thanks